# Facing errors during openstack-devstack installation?

Tags: linux, openstack

We were trying to install openstack-devstack on Redhat linux. When I executed the below command

```
      [stack@xyz123 devstack]$ ./stack.sh
```

During installation we were getting the below error.

```
   Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64. 1:5.5.47.1.el7_2 - u due to obsoletes from installed mysql-community-libs-5.7.12-1.el7/x86_64
   Restarting dependency Resolution with new changes
   Running transaction check
   Package mariadb-libs.x86_64. 1:5.5.47.1.el7_2 will be installed
   Processing Dependency : mariadb-libs = 1.5.5.47-1.el7_2 for package: 1: mariadb-devel-5.5.47-1
  Finished dependency resolution
  Error : Package : 1: maria-db-devel-5.5.47-1/el7_2
             Requires: mariadb-libs(x86-64)= 1:5.5.47-1.el7_2
            Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.35-3.el7.x86_64
                    mariadb-libs(x86-64) =1:5.5.35-3.el7
   You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
   You could try running: rpm -VA --nofiles --nodigest
```

Note: MySQL is already installed on my machine. And I cannot remove MySQL as it is being used by some other users.

Answer (score 0):

Since devstack is a development tool, it's probably best to install it in a VM or a separate machine where you do development.

Comment: I was trying to install on a separate machine - Redhat 7. This machine has a MySQL installation. Unfortunately I cannot remove it. How can I resolve the above error? What is the actual cause to the above error?

Comment: Actually I heard RHEL7 installation comes with Maria-db. Does rhel's Maria-db is getting conflict with maria-db that is being installed by openstack? Or conflicting with mysql?

Comment: looks like a version conflict. Have you enabled mariadb explicitly? something is off, it should default to mysql anyway https://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack/devstack-plugin-mariadb/tree/README.rst